# What is the proper term for "selection boxes" (e.g. selecting multiple items in Finder)? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, terminology

I don't know how to describe this, I am looking for a React component which enables me to have e.g. 3 elements on the screen and when the user clicks, holds and forms a square, these 3 elements are being 'selected'.

I am not asking for a specific recommendation, but for the name of this feature in general. I cannot find anything, I have tried 'selection box' and 'react select elements' but I only find dropdowns & forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like the following:

- [Drag to Select](http://pablofierro.github.io/react-drag-select/)
- [Selectable](http://unclecheese.github.io/react-selectable/example/)